# Need to take the investment

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

There is such a model

To order_id => client => city

I need something to search for the city, that is, I need to be able to throw the id into a variable,
for example

```
  let matchCriteria = [{ shop_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(shopId) }];
  searchCity &&
    matchCriteria.push({ city: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(order_id => client => city) });
```

Comment: Hello, please take two or three more minutes to write your question. As it is, we have very vague idea of what you are trying to achieve. Please prefer to form your question with "I have tried this, but X happens instead of Y" instead of "I need"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.